# Visual Studio Form Designer Unhandled Exception Designer Disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, properties, windows-forms-designer, designer

i have a **user control (A)** that contains some other controls (X,Y,Z) and **i want to hide the default properties** of the user control (A) **from the properties tool box** in the visual studio designer if the user control (A) is used on any form.
After some research i found out that my user control needs a custom designer and in that custom designer the **typedescriptor** of the default properties will be changed so that the property owns the **BrowsableAttribute** with value false.

So far so good, that works fine for most of the properties. But if i want to hide the **Dock-Property**, visual studio shows me an **unhandled exception**.
I can click on the controls (A) or (B,C,D) in the form but the first thing that is **noticeable is that the dotted border around each control is missing and if i want to drag the control, this exception is thrown**:

[image]

If i **manually override** the **Dock-Property** in my user control and **set** the **BrowsableAttribute** to false, **no exception will be thrown**.
I don't know why this happens and how to get control over this behavior. I can't also find anything on the web.

Can someone explain what happens there and how to manage this issue?

I have attached a small demo project without any special additional references.

[Download Solution from OneDrive](http://1drv.ms/1BqNNIo)

**Control A**

```
[Designer(typeof(CustomControlDesigner))]
public partial class ControlA : UserControl
{
    public ControlA()
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // ControlA
        // 
        AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
        AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
        BackColor = Color.Red;
        Name = "ControlA";
        ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private IContainer components = null;
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**Custom Designer**

```
public class CustomControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    protected override void PreFilterProperties(IDictionary properties)
    {
        var propertiesToHide = new []
        {
            "Tag",
            "Dock"
        };

        foreach (string propname in propertiesToHide)
        {
            var prop = (PropertyDescriptor)properties[propname];
            if (prop != null)
            {
                AttributeCollection runtimeAttributes = prop.Attributes;
                Attribute[] attrs = new Attribute[runtimeAttributes.Count + 1];
                runtimeAttributes.CopyTo(attrs, 0);
                attrs[runtimeAttributes.Count] = new BrowsableAttribute(false);
                prop = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(GetType(), propname, prop.PropertyType, attrs);
                properties[propname] = prop;
            }
        }
        base.PreFilterProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        controlA1 = new ControlA();
        SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // controlA1
        // 
        controlA1.Location = new Point(81, 81);
        controlA1.Name = "controlA1";
        controlA1.Size = new Size(150, 150);
        controlA1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
        AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
        ClientSize = new Size(284, 261);
        Controls.Add(controlA1);
        Name = "Form1";
        Text = "Form1";
        ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private ControlA controlA1;
}
```

Comment: Well, you're unlucky, the Dock property is special to the Winforms designer.  The ControlDesigner class uses it explicitly in its code for example.  You need to do this the way that [.NET classes do it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SplitterPanel.cs,321ed1676ebe6a46).

Comment: What are the reasons to hide `Tag` and `Dock`? I was hiding `Autosize` myself, clearly because my control doesn't uses it. But **all** controls in winforms are using `Dock` and have `Tag` (tag is very nice to have). So, why?

Comment: Cause the Controls i have to design are used in an own GUI Designer at runtime so that user can click their GUI with Drag'n'Drop and without Visual Studio. Thats not to build a second Visual Studio but for our special case the user/coworker should not play with properties they should'nt use.

Comment: Btw i have feared that this will be the only way but i don't know where the difference is wether i add it static or dynamic. The GUI Designer uses this Designer-Class and seaches for Browsable-Attributes and in both cases the Properties have this attribute. Maybe this is just a special case and every control designer has resigned to inherit this feature for all controls.